# How to call HTTPS authentication using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, curl, http-headers

I was wondering if someone could help me with the coding I need to use on JavaScript(Google Script) for authentication over HTTPS.

All requests must be made over HTTPS. All data is sent and received as JSON.

When making requests, you receive data as JSON by properly setting the Accept header to application/json, as shown in the example below:

$ curl https://yoursite.desk.com/api/v2/cases/:id 
-u email:password 
-H 'Accept: application/json'

This was the HTTPS authentication provided by the website API. And I was wondering if someone could help with calling this using JavaScript.

Comment: Front end JavaScript or using node.js?

Answer (score 0):

#### I've been unable to test this well, but it should work

```
var ajax = function(url, user, pass, cb) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = readyOrNot;

    function readyOrNot() {
        if (xhr.readyState < 4 || xhr.status !== 200) return;

        xhr.readyState === 4 && cb(xhr);
    }

    xhr.open('GET', url, true, user, pass);
    xhr.send();
}
```

#### then you can do something like:

```
var url ='http://some.thingy.biz/api/v2/:id';
ajax(url, 'myUser', 'myPass', function(data) {
   ... cool data stuff ...
});
```